# Upload multiple images, TokenMismatch Error although I do have the token in the form. Any ideas?

Tags: html, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to upload multiple images at the same time and after the request, display them on the same page, beneath the form such that later (after multiple uploads) I can select which pictures i would like to keep. I used all the posible answers found here ([How to upload multiple files using PHP, jQuery and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295746/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-php-jquery-and-ajax),
    [Uploading Multiple Files using AJAX and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394069/uploading-multiple-files-using-ajax-and-php) ) , but no success.

I keep getting TokenMismatchException

500 (Internal Server Error) + TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="container upload-picture-device">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-1 col-xs-12"></div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
             <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <span class="btn btn-de-pe btn-file">
                                Choose <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="files[]" class="pics" multiple>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-upload" readonly>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 text-left">
                <button id="uploadPhotos" type="submit" class="btn-continua">Upload picture</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        </form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#uploadForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = new FormData();
    var files = document.getElementsByClassName('pics');
    for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        form.append("files[pic" + i + "]", files[i][0]); // add receipt to form
    }
    form.append('action', 'upload-photos'); // specify action

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{url("/photos/device")}}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            // I have some error handling logic here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Post the error message !

Comment: You are doing an AJAX request and not sending the csrf token.

Comment: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68: + 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you have 2 forms

`<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

```
var form = new FormData();
```

and I think "TokenMismatchException" is coming from the second form so you can append csrf_token with the second form

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761987/jquery-post-formdata-and-csrf-token-together)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer , I was missing $('form')[0] from new FormData($('form')[0]).

Answer (score 0):

You are making an AJAX request and not sending the csrf token. You are creating new empty form data, not using the actual form.

You can check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf) to see the different ways to include the csrf token in a request.

Basically you can do something like this, before the ajax request:

```
form.append('_token', {{ csrf_token() }})
```